# Javascript what is "=>" operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I decided to get myself up-to-date with JavaScript and have come across this operator in multiple places ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and [here](http://raganwald.com/2015/06/17/functional-mixins.html)) but have can't figure out what it is, how to use it. And google doesn't allow you to search for symbols so that didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.